# Anaconda install fails on Red Hat 7.7 system

Tags: bash, anaconda, rhel7

I want to install Anaconda on system.

Running Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh on Red Hat system hangs at

> PREFIX=/home/user1/anaconda3
>
> Unpacking payload ...
>
> 0%| ---- |0/291 [00:00

Running on Ubuntu or CentOS docker container works fine.

Tried setting temp path to different location.

Also... found the failing command in install script

> -bash-4.2$ ls
>
> conda.exe  LICENSE.txt  pkgs  postconda.tar.bz2  preconda.tar.bz2
>
> -bash-4.2$ ./conda.exe constructor --prefix $PWD --extract-conda-pkgs
>
> 0%| ---                                  |0/291 [00:00

In install script

> 360 "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs || exit 1

Comment: What error are you getting?  I am getting "preconda.tar.bz2: No such file or directory".  Four hours after you.

Comment: I wasn't getting an error.  It would just stay stuck there at zero %

Answer (score 1):

We got past it by using an older installer

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

It's still an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I ran into this issue on an Amazon Linux AMI. Got past it by using the installer Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh.

Comment: Solution for me was on older version; On a RedHat 8 machine I used the latest version ( Anaconda3-2023.09.0-Linux-x86_64.sh ) and failed without any meaningful message! Then, I randomly picked an older version from the archive ( Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh ) and simply worked!

Answer (score 0):

We solved by the problem by using an old version of the installer from 1/2/2019.  Miniconda3-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh.  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/

Answer (score 0):

I'am blocked also ...maybe a lock file somewhere ?
(centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this is because dd fails on the host (e.g., getting permission denied).

A possible solution is to have one copy of the miniconda installer that is correct (matches SHA256) and another modified version.

To obtain the outputs from dd, work on a machine that does not fail. In the modified script replace the variable THIS_PATH with the path to the correct installer. Further modify the script by piping the output from dd for "Unpacking payload" to some binary file (much like conda.exe was produced) rather than the default to conda.exe command to extract-tar. After that, exit the script. You should have two files conda.exe and the binary file that would be piped to "conda.exe ... --extract-tar ...". Copy these to a directory on the dd-faulty machine.

On the dd-faulty machine use another modified script derived from the original. Change THIS_PATH to match the correct script. Change CONDA_EXEC variable to match the location where you copied conda.exe, comment out the dd code, and run conda.exe --extract-tar using the contents of the binary file produced above, e.g. something like:

`cat conda_exec_input.bin | "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs || exit 1`

But now I run into another error, likely due to lack of some features in this remote environment (no sudo access unfortunately): "conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted"

Hence the reason why this may be just a potential solution, not a verified one.

---

Additional info: setting TMPDIR to an exec location gets past the libz error. However, there's a further fail in the installer:

`File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__`

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

`[287] Failed to execute script entry_point`

Unfortunately can't seem to get farther with this!